Word Interop change text of paragraph before a table
I want to change the text af a paragraph. Thought it is totally simple - until there was a table.
Actually it is just one line of code:
activeDocument.Paragraphs[2].Range.Text = "abcd" + "\r";
Word Document before
line1
line2
line3

Word Document after
line1
abcd   -> OK: text in paragraph replaced
line3

But with table it becomes strange (see below). The second paragraph is moved inside the table.
Word Document before
line1
line2
+-------+
| line3 |
+-------+

Word Document after
line1
+-------+
| abcd  |  -> NOK: text in paragraph replaced - but moved also into table
|       |
| line3 |
+-------+

how can i prevent the paragraph from being moved to the table?

I guess this is because paragraph is merged into the table when you overwrite its terminating carriage return character. I can think of several solutions to avoid that. Let's implement them as an extension method of Paragraph interface.
Exclude terminating CR from the range
public static class ParagraphExtensions
{
    public static void SetText(this Paragraph paragraph, string text)
    {
        var range = paragraph.Range;
        var textRange = range.Document.Range(range.Start, range.End - 1);
        textRange.Text = text;
    }
}

Use TypeText() method of Selection to change paragraph's text
public static class ParagraphExtensions
{
    public static void SetText(this Paragraph paragraph, string text)
    {
        paragraph.Range.Select();
        paragraph.Application.Selection.TypeText(text);
    }
}

The drawback is that it changes the selection.
Add brand new paragraph
public static class ParagraphExtensions
{
    public static void SetText(this Paragraph paragraph, string text)
    {
        // insert new paragraph before this paragraph
        var newParagraph = paragraph.Range.Document.Paragraphs.Add(paragraph.Range);
        newParagraph.Range.Text = text + "\r";
        // delete original paragraph
        paragraph.Range.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}


The usage of the extension methods for each of the options above is
activeDocument.Paragraphs[2].SetText("abcd");


Reducing the range by on 'range.Document.Range(range.Start, range.End - 1)' works for me
